# How can I fix an issue I'm having with react-native-vision-camera ​

Tags: react-native, react-native-vision-camera

every time I change the state of isActive several times the app crashes and closes automatically
When the QR code is read, a modal appears to make updates to a list and the first time it works correctly but from the second time onwards it always gives an error closing my application
I'm using it this way

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text } from 'react-native';
import { useAppState } from '@react-native-community/hooks';
import { Camera, useCameraDevice, useCodeScanner } from 'react-native-vision-camera';
import { useIsFocused } from '@react-navigation/core';
import styles from './styles';

export default function ContainerQrcodeScanner({
  setDataScanned,
}: {
  readonly setDataScanned: (dataqrcode: string) => void;
}) {
  const isFocused = useIsFocused();
  const appState = useAppState();
  const isActive = isFocused && appState === 'active';
  const device = useCameraDevice('back');
  const codeScanner = useCodeScanner({
    codeTypes: ['qr', 'ean-13'],
    onCodeScanned: (codes) => {
      console.log(`Scanned ${codes.length} codes!`);
      console.log(codes[0].value);
      setDataScanned(codes[0].value ?? '');
    },
  });
  if (device == null)
    return (
      <View>
        <Text>dispositivo sem camera</Text>
      </View>
    );

  return (
    <View style={styles.barcodebox}>
      <Camera
        style={styles.barcodebox}
        device={device}
        isActive={isActive}
        codeScanner={codeScanner}
        torch={'off'}
        onError={(e) => console.log(e)}
      />
    </View>
  );
}
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { View } from 'react-native';
import { ModalUpdateDevice } from './components/modal';
import styles from './styles';
import ContainerQrcodeScanner from './components/ContainerQrcode';
interface typeshandleBarCodeScanned {
  type: string;
  data: string;
}
export default function PageScanner() {
  const [scannerActive, setScannerActive] = useState<boolean>(true);
  const [dataScanned, setDataScanned] = useState<string>('');
  useEffect(() => {
    setScannerActive(true);
    console.log('s');
  }, [dataScanned]);
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      {dataScanned ? (
        <ModalUpdateDevice
          setModalVisible={() => {
            setScannerActive(true);
            setDataScanned('');
          }}
          modalVisible={scannerActive}
          data={dataScanned}
        />
      ) : (
        <ContainerQrcodeScanner setDataScanned={(data) => setDataScanned(data)} />
      )}
    </View>
  );
}
```

I tried everything and I don't know what to do

Comment: try use alternative react-native-qrcode-scanner, I'm using it on my last project